# A household item

Tags: riddle, word

> I am soft, only if you put something in my specified area for it.
>
> If you touch me in other areas, I am hard.
>
> I am warm and large.
>
> There are many nouns with me in front of them.
>
> When you are on me, you tend to go to imaginary places, only to realize that this is all in your head.
>
> I have four feet and a back bone as wide as me, but taller than me.
>
> You would place a "pain pill" on me.

---

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> A bed?

I am soft, only if you put something in my specified area for it.

> The top of a bed (ie. on the mattress) is soft

If you touch me in other areas, I am hard.

> The bed frame and posts and headboard are hard.

I am warm and large.

> Beds are indeed warm and large

There are many nouns with me in front of them.

> Bedframe, bedpost, bedbug, etc.

When you are on me, you tend to go to imaginary places, only to realize that this is all in your head.

> Sounds like dreaming when you're asleep

I have four feet and a back bone as wide as me, but taller than me.

> Beds have four legs and a bed backframe. (Thanks to OP!)

You would place a "pain pill" on me.

> Could this refer to a pill-ow?

Comment: For the 7th clue i was talking about a orq onpxsenzr (rot13)

Comment: the orq onpxsenzr is the pain pill? I thought that was the back bone?

Comment: Yall sleepin' on fancy (orqf)rot13 and I'm over here on my (pbhpu)- I've got my priorities.

Comment: @El-Guest it is the backbone

Comment: @TrooperZ is the pain pill as described? LOL rot13(orqf) are _much_ more comfortable, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @El-Guest the pain pill is correct

Comment: What if you had a (gjva fvmr orq)- would the backbone still be taller?

Comment: My bed is a twin and the backbone is taller. Must be cuz i got it from ikea.

Answer (score 1):

> A couch

I am soft, only if you put something in my specified area for it.

> Soft when you fill the cushions with fluff

If you touch me in other areas, I am hard.

> the wood beams holding the sofa up are hard

I am warm and large.

> very

There are many nouns with me in front of them.

> John's couch. living room couch, plastic couch, etc.

When you are on me, you tend to go to imaginary places, only to realize that this is all in your head.

> you can fall asleep on one.

I have four feet and a back bone as wide as me, but taller than me.

> It has four legs and generally some sort of "spine" down the middle to support it. It will be longer due to couches being longer than height.

You would place a "pain pill" on me.

> My parents lose their pills and phones by leaving it on the couch all the time!

The Note:

> You can do some dirty things on a couch.

Comment: This is a good answer too! (The Note: section for mature audiences only ;P)

Comment: Close... you got the fact that it is a piece of sheavgher (rot13).